# testing for significance of a low-dimensional structure (e.g., collinearity)

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, pca, bootstrap

I have p dependent variables $y_i (i=1,\cdots,p)$ sampled n times and a single independent variable $x$. All my dependent variables can be modeled by a linear regression on the independent variable as
$$y_i = b_i + m_i x.$$

Of course all dependent variables are directly interrelated by a linear regression. However, my hypothesis goes one step further and is interested to test if these variables are all linearly dependent (or co-linear if you will) without an intercept. In other words, there exists
some constants $\alpha_i$ and $Y^\star \in \mathbb{R}^n$ satisfying
$$ \alpha_i y_i = y^\star \; \forall i=1,...,p.$$

Some thoughts that I have :

- To recover the underlying low-dimensional (1D) structure, I'm applying PCA without centering to create the low-rank approximate matrix  from the 1st principle component. This is giving me an explained variance. But how can I generate null distribution of explained variances for this?
- Let's say I also run a PCA with centering to see the effect of having an intercept. Is there a way to test the explained variances in both cases (with our without centering) are different or not? Maybe, with a lack of F-test by adjusting for the additional DOF of the model gained with including intercepts via centering.
- Along similar lines, I thought of simulating a null distribution by adding a random intercept to each of the dependent variables, thus preserving their association with the independent variable while perturbing their collinearity. However, I am not sure if that's a good idea or not. I don't wanna create a spurious null distribution by adding very large intercept.
- Alternatively, I can perhaps do a pairwise regression fit between variables and test for the significance of the intercept?
- Can I take a bootstrapping approach?
- Since my hypothesis can be rephrased as data matrix having rank 1, any one of my dependent variables should be written as a linear combination of others. I was wondering if I could construct a superior regression model with new dependent and independent variables as
  $$ Y = [y_1^T, y_2^T, ..., y_p^T]^T  \text{  stacking dependent variables} \\ X = \begin{bmatrix}y_2 & y_3 & \cdots & y_p \\ y_1 & y_3 & \cdots & y_p \\ \cdots \\ y_1 & y_2 & \cdots & y_{p-1}\end{bmatrix} \text{ each row block missing one dependent variable}$$
  This can be used to maybe test if the regression intercept is zero or not.

Any help is appreciated greatly.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "generate null distribution of explained variances"?  What is your probability model?

Comment: I meant to say either through a bootstrap or shuffling.
Is this more clear? If not, I'm guessing I might have used that phrase without knowing what I'm talking about

Comment: Are you perhaps asking how to test the hypothesis that the response lies along a one-dimensional (affine) subspace, rather than requiring two or more dimensions?  This would be a goodness of fit test -- and measuring "explained variance" usually won't do a good job assessing it.

Comment: I think that's a good way of phrasing my question.

Comment: Can you tell me what would be a good keyword to search for use of goodness of fit test for this purpose?

Comment: I guess there is one caveat I feel the need to clarify in case it wasn't clear in my question. This is not affine 1D vs 2/3 D in the classical sense. My response variables are definitely all 1d if they are centered to origin because of the common regression link. However, I claim that they are 1D without centering.